# Adding an element a binary search tree

Tags: java

Trying to add an element to BST. I have an idea of how to do it, but my implementation is destructive, and the original root is not preserved (so the tree basically becomes useless). The tree is based on lists, and this method is based on recursion. My real problem is preserving the original root. I'm using generics.

So far what I have:

```
public void addElement(E elem, Node<E> root) {
```

Create node with a value of elem, call it newNode

Case 1: Tree is empty

```
root = newNode();
return; //End of method.
```

Otherwise, keep searching the tree (by comparing the value of out node a with the root of the tree.

```
if (!root.hasLeft() && !root.hasRight) { //if the root in question has no children
    if (elem < rootValue) {     //Set the element as the left element
      root.setLeft(newNode);
    }
    else {                      //Set the element as the right element.
      root.setRight(newNode);
    }
  } 

  else {

    if (E < root.getElem()) {              
//This is where the value of our node is compared to the value of the root, which we passed in.
//(I know that we can't use the < and > operators with generics, but assume it works).

  root = root.getLeft() //Left node is new root
  addElement(elem, root); //Call the method again
}
else {  
  root = root.getRight(); //Right node is new root
  addElement(elem, root)  //Call method again
}
  }
```

}

Forgive me if this is a duplicate/vague question, this is my first post on SO, and I'm kind of noob.

Comment: can you show your implementation of `setLeft` and `setRight`?

Comment: This algorithm is wrong now as is. He's only setting a child if it has no children. But in some cases, when you have only 1 child you also want to set it to the other one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!root.hasLeft() && !root.hasRight) {
```

This logic is wrong. You're only considering "setting" the left child, if you have neither a left nor right child. This change should do it:

```
void addElement(elem, root)
{
    if (elem < root.value) {  
      if(!root.hasLeft())
          root.setLeft(newNode);
      else
          addElement(elem, root.getLeft());
    }
    else {    
      if(!root.hasRight())   
          root.setRight(newNode);
      else             
          addElement(elem, root.getRight());
    }
}
```

You should not be changing root of the class, just passing it into the next method call. This should preserve root.

By the way, I assume you have `rootValue = root.value` somewhere or somethign similar?